# How can my organisation's published reports get indexed by Google Scholar?

Tags: publications, online-publication, google-scholar

My organisation (i.e. my employer) publishes peer-reviewed research reports in the form of a journal series via its website.  The organisation alone publishes the reports and they are not published in conjunction with any publishing agency or academic body.  The research reports are written and peer reviewed by academics and the research activity funding is managed by my organisation.

The research reports are in PDF form (with metadata attached), and are listed on a web page containing metadata in the form of the fields required by Google Scholar.  The Google Scholar submission process was completed ten months ago in March 2016.  There was one issue identified: there is not a volume/issue listing of the reports, they are discoverable via the website search engine.

The website has been submitted to Google Scholar with example URLs, but to date, the body of research that is made available via the organisation's website is not included in the Google Scholar index.

Where the research reports are also stored and published by university databases, these do appear in the index.

Additionally, citations to the research reports do often appear in the index without any link to the location of the report.  Ideally, we would like to enable these citations to also show links to the online reports.

I had thought that the form and structure of the research report publication was suitable, but our organisation's website has not been included in Google Scholar indexing.

Some suggestions [on the Google Scholar website](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html) are to use a journal publishing service (established journal hosting services) or recommended software such as [Open Journal Systems](https://openjournalsystems.com/).

**What process should I follow to investigate or progress this issue further?**

I suspect that I'm not looking in the right place in my investigations, so I need some direction.

Comment: Have you asked the Google Scholar support? What did they say?

Comment: I'm not aware of Google Scholar support - I'm only aware of contacting Google Scholar by submitting your publication.  Do you have those details?

Comment: You can contact them here: https://support.google.com/scholar/contact/general

Comment: OK thanks David, I've now submitted my question via that URL.

Comment: You can access a lot of information here: https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/publishers.html#questions - have a look at the very first of the general question, maybe you will find your answer there. Good luck!

Comment: It is strange that the google scholar hasn't indexed the work at your institution. It has indexed my undergrad thesis and I don't even known how to find it!. Is there any block on your site that prevent google indexing it (robots.txt preventing them, you need to log in to see them, it is only accessible if you are at certain location) ? See [this link](https://scholar.google.com/intl/en/scholar/inclusion.html) from the site linked by Doc and then contact them through [this form](https://partnerdash.google.com/partnerdash/d/scholarinclusions#p:id=new)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We found that by submitting our content to SSRN we were able to see the content (once approved and distributed by SSRN) subsequently indexed by Google Scholar.  This method is, therefore, an appropriate solution in our situation for this problem, without the need to restructure our website.